# Probability and forecasting fields are not filling by default in Custom Opportunity VF page..?

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, dynamic-visualforce

In Custom VF Page for Opportunity, when selecting Stage field.. Probability and forecasting fields are not filling by default. In Standard Opportunity page, if we select Stage field.. by default Probability and Forecasting fields are filled. Is there any solution for this...?

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to do this as far as I can see. You can do it the old fashion way by creation a partial page update and querying/updating the probability value based on the stage.

1) Create an extension to your VF 2) Add actionSupport to the Stage field with action="{!changeStageName}" 3) Make sure the propability field is in the rendered/rerendered area 4) In your extension class, make sure to make the method changeStageName 5) Set the probability based on stage chosen by querying the Sales process (OpportunityStage).

This link has example codes -.

http://opfocus.com/blog/dynamically-updating-probability-when-selecting-stage-with-visualforce-2/

Good Luck.

Thx

William